# blob created by createObjectURL save to database

Tags: javascript, html

So, basically I have an input file browser. I can select mp3 files in my local disk, then convert it in client side to blob using `URL.createObjectURL()`, then play it using HTML5 audio. If I save this blob url to database, can I play it again in another time, so that I dont have to select the file again and again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, [because](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL):

> The URL lifetime is tied to the document in the window on which it was created.

You have to store the whole file/blob either on the client (FileSystem API) or upload it.

If you want to upload it, you can directly use XMLHTTPRequest, as the [send](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#send()) method supports Blobs. (Note: you can't use a blob url, you need the Blob itself.)